Displaying the literal char for all ASCII codes
Have a problem with a challenge in my C++ class.
The goal is to output all ASCII characters from 0-127 with 16 characters per line.
What we have had an issue with is certain chars such as 10 (\n) are doing what they're supposed to do rather than display "\n". My instructor does not know the solution to this either.
This is what I have:
int main ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 127; i++) {
        cout << setw(4) << i << ": " << (char)i << "  ";
        
        if ((i + 1) % 16 == 0) {
            cout << endl;
            // Not sure why this doesn't seem to be displaying correctly? Possibly it's because of what some of the earlier ascii characters do/are
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


We have found a couple possible solutions including Raw, which does not seem to work with variables.
haven't managed to make fprint work for it either

"The goal is to output all ASCII characters from 0-127" - That's not possible. Quite a few of those are non printable characters.

It's quite easy to create a function which takes a character as input (argument) and returns a string with the "escape" character. So e.g. '\n' returns the string "\\n".

my guess is that your code works perfectly fine and does produce expected output, its just that your expectations are off. If your intstructor doesnt know you have to find someone else to clarify what your task is exactly.

Almost all values below 32 are control characters. They're not supposed to print anything (but where intended to do something with tele-typewriters). Lookup an ascii table online... you will see. (e.g. character "7" would ring a bell)

But remember, not all character are actually printable, or have an escaped equivalent.

if you are supposed to print \n for the new line character and similar for others, I would use a look up table of strings rather than relying (char)i. 127 is not that much and tables online are abundant

And generally, when you feel the need to do a C-style explicit conversion (a cast like (char)i) then that should almost always be taken as a sign that you're doing something wrong. For your use-case use static_cast<char>(i) instead.

Your code (once the missing #includes are added) works as designed.  Instead of the character, the code at the link outputs "(character)", and you see there are 16 sets of output per line.   The issue is what others have mentioned -- you can't simply output control characters (characters below 32) and expect the terminal to not go nuts.   Also it is surprising your teacher is not aware of this -- it should be universally known by anyone teaching programming that uses ASCII that below 32 are control characters.

ASCII Chart note the characters that are non-printable.  Also includes a program that prints the printable ones.

If your instructor cannot show you a correct solution to your honework, they are not qualified to teach that particular class.

Thanks, This came from a textbook with no example of the answer and is new to her as of this semester. We thought we may be missing something.

How to represent the non-printable characters in printed output. If it is left out, then the correct thing to do is contact the provider of the specification and get clarification on how this is to be handled. This seems to be your teacher and seems to have failed. Which leaves you with trying to come up with a solution an negotiating its acceptability with your client/boss/teacher.

Does the professor not vet their own materials? New book and all of that is not an excuse for a lazy professor who assigns work without even looking at it first. Even if they don't have control of what book is chosen, they control what they assign. I've taught at the university level, and your professor is looking like part of the reason that professors and universities get the rap that they do.

One old way of doing (most of) this is to represent the characters from 0x00 to 0x1f as a "^" followed by the corresponding character from the range 0x40 to 0x5f. Another way is to use names associated with these values such as NUL, BEL, LF, and CR. See chart A third way is to use one of a variety of sets of glyphs later invented to reuse these values for new purposes. These can give 16 character representations per line, but may be more total characters per line.

My instructor does not know the solution to this either.  But... but... but... it is your instructors assignment.  Left to my own devices, I'd use ISO 2047 glyphs for the control characters 00-1F, 20, and 7F.

@DylanCarney -- This is an adaptation of the answer given by AndreasWeizel and the comment by AviBerger.  But as mentioned, you need to go back to your professor and state you know what the problem is, but the instructor has to tell you how to represent those control characters in print form.

@PaulMcKenzie: The program you posted in your previous comment invokes undefined behavior for the non-printable character with the ASCII code 127, due to accessing the array controls out of bounds. You can easily confirm this by compiling your program with -fsanitize=address.

@AndreasWenzel -- Fixed.

You are attempting to print the ASCII characters in the entire range 0 to 127. However, not all of these ASCII characters are printable. Attempting to print a non-printable character may mess up the text in your terminal window, because it may have a special meaning to the terminal (for example if it is a control character).
You can use the function std::isprint to determine whether a character is printable. If that function reports that the character is printable, you can print it, otherwise you can print some other placeholder character to mark it as unprintable, such as X. Here is an example:
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 127; i++)
    {
        std::cout <<
            std::setw(4) << i << ": " <<
            ( std::isprint(i) ? (char)i : 'X' ) <<
            "  ";
        
        if ( (i + 1) % 16 == 0 )
        {
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

This program has the following output:
   0: X     1: X     2: X     3: X     4: X     5: X     6: X     7: X     8: X     9: X    10: X    11: X    12: X    13: X    14: X    15: X  
  16: X    17: X    18: X    19: X    20: X    21: X    22: X    23: X    24: X    25: X    26: X    27: X    28: X    29: X    30: X    31: X  
  32:      33: !    34: "    35: #    36: $    37: %    38: &    39: '    40: (    41: )    42: *    43: +    44: ,    45: -    46: .    47: /  
  48: 0    49: 1    50: 2    51: 3    52: 4    53: 5    54: 6    55: 7    56: 8    57: 9    58: :    59: ;    60: <    61: =    62: >    63: ?  
  64: @    65: A    66: B    67: C    68: D    69: E    70: F    71: G    72: H    73: I    74: J    75: K    76: L    77: M    78: N    79: O  
  80: P    81: Q    82: R    83: S    84: T    85: U    86: V    87: W    88: X    89: Y    90: Z    91: [    92: \    93: ]    94: ^    95: _  
  96: `    97: a    98: b    99: c   100: d   101: e   102: f   103: g   104: h   105: i   106: j   107: k   108: l   109: m   110: n   111: o  
 112: p   113: q   114: r   115: s   116: t   117: u   118: v   119: w   120: x   121: y   122: z   123: {   124: |   125: }   126: ~   127: X  


Printing X for non-printable characters is probably not the best choice, since that is a real printable character 88. At least do something to distinguish between them, like (X). Otherwise, do something more descriptive, like [NoPr], etc.

@RemyLebeau: If I changed the length of the output for non-printable characters (as you suggested), then the alignment would be wrong and would have to be adapted, which would require additional changes to the program posted by OP. These additional changes would distract from the actual issue. Therefore, I decided not to change the length of the output for non-printable characters, and the placeholder character X seemed like a good choice to me.

Since setw() is already being used for the index output, it can be used for the character output, too. Then everything will still line up.

Modern terminals do not work like old time DOS terminals. You cannot just write control character codes to video memory and have their glyph appear on screen.
Instead, you must write the Unicode values to the display. If you use UTF-8 you can get it to work nicely on both Windows and on *nixen.
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _WIN32
  #include <windows.h>
  
  struct OutputCodePage
  {
    UINT original_cp;
    OutputCodePage( UINT cp ) : original_cp{GetConsoleOutputCP()} { SetConsoleOutputCP( cp ); }
   ~OutputCodePage() { SetConsoleOutputCP( original_cp ); }
  };
  
  OutputCodePage output_code_page( CP_UTF8 );
#endif

const char * CP437[] =  // 0 (nul) --> 32 (space)
{
  " ", "☺", "☻", "♥", "♦", "♣", "♠", "•", "◘", "○", "◙", "♂", "♀", "♪", "♫", "☼",
  "►", "◄", "↕", "‼", "¶", "§", "▬", "↨", "↑", "↓", "→", "←", "∟", "↔", "▲", "▼",
  " ", "!", "\"","#", "$", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/",
  "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ":", ";", "<", "=", ">", "?",
  "@", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
  "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "[", "\"","]", "^", "_",
  "`", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o",
  "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "{", "|", "}", "~", "⌂",
  "Ç", "ü", "é", "â", "ä", "à", "å", "ç", "ê", "ë", "è", "ï", "î", "ì", "Ä", "Å",
  "É", "æ", "Æ", "ô", "ö", "ò", "û", "ù", "ÿ", "Ö", "Ü", "¢", "£", "¥", "₧", "ƒ",
  "á", "í", "ó", "ú", "ñ", "Ñ", "ª", "º", "¿", "⌐", "¬", "½", "¼", "¡", "«", "»",
  "░", "▒", "▓", "│", "┤", "╡", "╢", "╖", "╕", "╣", "║", "╗", "╝", "╜", "╛", "┐",
  "└", "┴", "┬", "├", "─", "┼", "╞", "╟", "╚", "╔", "╩", "╦", "╠", "═", "╬", "╧",
  "╨", "╤", "╥", "╙", "╘", "╒", "╓", "╫", "╪", "┘", "┌", "█", "▄", "▌", "▐", "▀",
  "α", "ß", "Γ", "π", "Σ", "σ", "µ", "τ", "Φ", "Θ", "Ω", "δ", "∞", "φ", "ε", "∩",
  "≡", "±", "≥", "≤", "⌠", "⌡", "÷", "≈", "°", "∙", "·", "√", "ⁿ", "²", "■", "\xA0"
};


int main()
{
  std::cout << "  +  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15\n";
  for (int y = 0;  y < 16;  y++)
  {
    std::cout << std::setw(3) << (y * 16);
    for (int x = 0;  x < 16;  x++)
    {
      std::cout << "  " << CP437[y * 16 + x];
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
}

That’ll get you:
  +  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
  0     ☺  ☻  ♥  ♦  ♣  ♠  •  ◘  ○  ◙  ♂  ♀  ♪  ♫  ☼
 16  ►  ◄  ↕  ‼  ¶  §  ▬  ↨  ↑  ↓  →  ←  ∟  ↔  ▲  ▼
 32     !  "  #  $  %  &  '  (  )  *  +  ,  -  .  /
 48  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  :  ;  <  =  >  ?
 64  @  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O
 80  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z  [  "  ]  ^  _
 96  `  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o
112  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z  {  |  }  ~  ⌂
128  Ç  ü  é  â  ä  à  å  ç  ê  ë  è  ï  î  ì  Ä  Å
144  É  æ  Æ  ô  ö  ò  û  ù  ÿ  Ö  Ü  ¢  £  ¥  ₧  ƒ
160  á  í  ó  ú  ñ  Ñ  ª  º  ¿  ⌐  ¬  ½  ¼  ¡  «  »
176  ░  ▒  ▓  │  ┤  ╡  ╢  ╖  ╕  ╣  ║  ╗  ╝  ╜  ╛  ┐
192  └  ┴  ┬  ├  ─  ┼  ╞  ╟  ╚  ╔  ╩  ╦  ╠  ═  ╬  ╧
208  ╨  ╤  ╥  ╙  ╘  ╒  ╓  ╫  ╪  ┘  ┌  █  ▄  ▌  ▐  ▀
224  α  ß  Γ  π  Σ  σ  µ  τ  Φ  Θ  Ω  δ  ∞  φ  ε  ∩
240  ≡  ±  ≥  ≤  ⌠  ⌡  ÷  ≈  °  ∙  ·  √  ⁿ  ²  ■  �

Remember, everything from 0..31 (and stuff after 126) is not necessarily a single character. In UTF-8, each “character” is a string. Hence the reason for the double-quotes in the source code.
P.S. As you can see this is for code page 437 — an old standard for DOS-like terminal displays. You will have to adjust your array of strings if you wish to display values for other code pages.
P.P.S. If all you want to do is display an int as a char, then you must stick to the displayable characters: 32..126.
  std::cout << (char)65 << ...;  // prints “A“


This answer makes no sense at all.

@n.m.couldbeanAI According to what metric? It is both correct (use UTF-8) and functional (output is provided).

Let's break it doewn sentence by sentence. "Modern terminals do not work like old time DOS terminals. You cannot just write control character codes to video memory and have their glyph appear on screen." Every terminal in existence is like that, no terminal ever used to show control characters, that's why they are called control characters in the first place. "Instead, you must write the Unicode values to the display." This makes no sense. Unicode control characters are the same as ASCII control characters, which have no printable representation. Continuing...

DOS terminals and vt100 terminals also work differently and what about tape output? Fact is that character codes are interpreted differently and there's no common consensus on how they should be interpreted.

No, let’s break that crap down. “Every terminal in existance is like that, no terminal ever used to show control characters”. Bull. I personally used to write DOS terminal control programs by directly frobbing memory in old times, as did every major terminal I/O library. “Unicode control characters are the same as ASCII...” Nice job of mixing meaning. No. The corresponding Unicode glyph values matching old glyphs corresponding to control characters appear higher up in the BMP than a single-byte character value.

"If you use UTF-8 you can get it to work nicely on both Windows and on *nixen." (Proceeds to show a program that is Windows-only, and that has CP437-specific glyphs) CP437 is not ASCII. ASCII characters 1 does't look like a smiley face. It has no look at all. CP437 character 1 does look like a smiley face, but the problem in hand is not to output a CP437 character table, it is to output an ASCII character table.

"I personally used to write DOS terminal control programs by directly frobbing memory in old times" By directly frobbing memory you are not working with a terminal any more. You are working with a thing that is able to displayt characters. A terminal has a specific interface.

This answer is generally bad. It doesn't answer the question asked by the OP.
